# Получить смещение из указателя на член

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть указатель на член, нужно получить числовое представление этого адреса, иными словами смещение. В коде вот так:

```
struct Foo
{
   int Bar;
};

auto pointer_to_member = &Foo::Bar;
auto  offset_of_member = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(pointer_to_member); // ошибка
```

Мой VisualC++ пишет ошибку:

> error C2440: `reinterpret_cast` cannot convert `int Foo::Bar *` to `uintptr_t`

Вопросы. Это что не по стандарту? И как получить смещение без `offsetof` так как в наличии уже готовый указатель на член?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSVC прав, так делать нельзя.

Через offsetof тоже не получится, потому что он работает только с именами полей, а не с указателями на них.

На MSVC может сработать `offsetof(Foo, *pointer_to_member)` из-за [особенностей реализации](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405854/confused-about-implemention-of-offsetof-in-msvc) этого самого `offsetof`. Но это не сооветствует стандарту и не работает как минимум на GCC.

---

Единственный полностью стандартный способ (насколько я знаю) - это создать объект, применить к нему указатель на поле, и вычесть из адреса поля адрес объекта:

```
Foo foo;
std::cout << (char *)&(foo.*pointer_to_member) - (char*)&foo;
```

---

Более удобный вариант - это сделать type-punning из указателя на поле в `uintptr_t` через `memcpy()`:

```
static_assert(sizeof(pointer_to_member) == sizeof(uintptr_t));
uintptr_t offset;
std::memcpy(&offset, &pointer_to_member, sizeof offset);
std::cout << offset;
```

Стандарт не гарантирует (насколько я знаю, опять же), что указатель на поле хранится как смещение, но это должно сработать на всех основных компиляторах.

Если под рукой нет уже готовых объектов `Foo`, я бы использовал именно этот способ.

Не стоит пробовать `reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t &>(pointer_to_member)`, или type-punning через `union`. И то, и другое - неопределенное поведение из-за нарушения strict aliasing.

---

Вот еще один способ. Выглядит удобно, но является неопределенным поведением из-за доступа по невалидному указателю.
[<sub>(Хотя дефолтная реализация `offsetof` в MSVC использует похожий трюк.)</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405854/confused-about-implemention-of-offsetof-in-msvc)

```
std::cout << (uintptr_t)&((Foo *)(0)->*pointer_to_member);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вашим способом нельзя. Открываем документацию на [offsetof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) и читаем

> offsetof cannot be implemented in standard C++ and requires compiler support

В gcc она сделана так

```
/* Offset of member MEMBER in a struct of type TYPE. */
#define offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER) __builtin_offsetof (TYPE, MEMBER)
```

Comment: Из-за совместимости возможно. Но что мешает разрешить приведение для `POD`?

Answer (score 0):

> Это что не по стандарту?

Да, это преобразование не по стандарту. Для указателей на член операцию преобразования к целому не определена. По факту указатель на член не является «указателем» в классическом понимании слова.

> И как получить смещение без offsetof так как в наличии уже готовый указатель на член?

Легально — ни как. Внутреннее устройство указателя на член определяется реализацией.

Не легально на большинстве систем можно сделать что-то такое, но это UB:

```
*(off_t*) &pointer_to_member
```

Comment: Если уж пользоваться UB, то можно сразу `(off_t &)pointer_to_member`.